# How to force files saved to the system's Downloads folder to be stored on an external drive?

Tags: macos, folders, data-transfer

I tried using symbolic links but they make me lose the default's Downloads icon which I don't want.

Is there a way I can just made files saved or downloaded to the system's Downloads folder be automatically moved and stored to an external drive?

Comment: Can you please continue the discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66755/discussion-on-answer-by-user3439894-how-to-force-files-saved-to-the-systems-dow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with a **Automator Folder Action** *workflow*:

- **Automator** > **New** > **Folder Action**

  - *Set*: **Folder Action receives files and folders added to Choose folder** *to:* **Downloads**
- *Add* the following **Actions**:
- **Get Folders Contents**

  - **[ ] Repeat for each subfolder found** - Leave unchecked.
- **Filter Finder Items**

  - **Find files where:**

    - **None of the following are true**
    - **Name ends with .download**

      - This is to avoid moving a file **Safari** is currently downloading.
    - **Kind is folder**

      - This is to avoid moving just the contents of the folder.
    - **Kind is other alias**
- **Move Finder Items**

  - **To: Downloads [ ] Replacing existing files**

    - Obviously in this instance **Downloads** is the one on the external drive.
    - You can choose to check or not: **Replacing existing files**
- **New Alias**

  - **In: Downloads**

    - Obviously in this instance **Downloads** is the one in your **Home** folder.
      If you do not want an alias created for each moved file, then omit this *action*.
- Save the **Automator Folder Action** *workflow*, e.g.; **Move to External Downloads**

To *stop* and or *remove* a **Folder Action**: In **Finder**, you can select the target **folder** and *right-click* on it and select **Folder Action Setup...** from the **Services** menu section of the **Context** menu.

---

[image: Automator Folder Action Workflow]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66755/discussion-on-answer-by-user3439894-how-to-force-files-saved-to-the-systems-dow).